# variadic templates same number of function arguments as in class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

**How to define method signature so it will accept same number of arguments as variadic template class definition?** For example how to define an Array class:

```
template<typename T, int... shape>
class Array
{
public:
    T& operator () (???);
};
```

So you will be able to call it like this:

```
Array<int, 3, 4, 5> a;
a(1, 2, 3) = 2;
```

Comment: I think this should work: `T& operator()(decltype(shape)... args);`

Comment: @0x499602D2 Which generalizes to: `T& operator()(decltype(shape, X())... args);` for changing the type.

Comment: @Deduplicator Indeed. But I assumed he wanted `int`.

Comment: Great, all approaches work, thanks everyone!

Comment: If you are just looking for a multi-dimensional version of `std::array`, you may be able to save yourself some work with the [variadic array alias trick](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6aa2c44c2174153f).

Comment: @Casey neat trick, but the context I'm working in is a bit different. I thought array is just clean example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
template<class T, int...Shape>
class Array {
  template<int>using index_t=int; // can change this
public:
  T& operator()(index_t<Shape>... is);
};
```

or:

```
template<class T, int...Shape>
class Array {
public:
  T& operator()(decltype(Shape)... is);
};
```

or:

```
template<class T, int...Shape>
class Array {
public:
  T& operator()(decltype(Shape, int())... is);
};
```

if you want to be able to change the type of the parameter to be different than `Shape`.

I find the `decltype` harder to understand a touch than the `using`, especially if you want to change the type of the parameter to be different than `int`.

Another approach:

```
template<class T, int...Shape>
class Array {
public:
  template<class...Args,class=typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args)==sizeof...(Shape)>::type>
  T& operator()(Args&&... is);
};
```

which uses SFINAE.  It does not enforce that the `Args` are integer types however.  We could add another clause if we wanted to (that all of the `Args` are convertible to `int`, say).

Yet another approach is to have your `operator()` take a package of values, like a `std::array<sizeof...(Shape), int>`.  Callers would have to:

```
Array<double, 3,2,1> arr;
arr({0,0,0});
```

use a set of `{}`s.

A final approach would be:

```
template<class T, int...Shape>
class Array {
public:
  template<class...Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&... is) {
    static_assert( sizeof...(Args)==sizeof...(Shapes), "wrong number of array indexes" );
  }
};
```

where we accept anything, then generate errors if it is the wrong number of arguments.  This generates very clean errors, but does not do proper SFINAE operator overloading.

I would recommend tag dispatching, but I don't see a way to make it much cleaner than the SFINAE solution, with the extra `decltype` and all, or better error messages than the `static_assert` version on the other hand.

Comment: It seems that checking for int conversion is superfluousl, Array<int, 1, 2, 3> a; a((char)1, (short)2, 2.0f); works anyway.

Comment: @DikobrAz the fear would be `Array<int, 1,2,3> a; a( "hello", "world", 3 );` would also work, and then break within the body of `operator()`, which is less than ideal.  If you have other metaprogramming code that is asking "can you be invoked with these arguments", you would prefer not to lie about it.

Comment: One should not disregard that every bit one does not have to assume, look up or still remember means that much more brain-power available for other things. Which makes me prefer the `decltype`. (Though it's not so bad when the definition of the extra type is directly above its use-site.)

Comment: @Yakk I see the point, I've mistakenly compared it with the initial approach with decltype.

Comment: I would argue that the types of the indices should be the same as the types of the extents, making the second option here "correct."

Comment: BTW, it seems that in gcc 4.6 only first approach works, http://goo.gl/e7CNBC, http://goo.gl/JHZO0n - if you don't use template alias, but typedef as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26766667/1008902

Comment: Any chance to compile this using visual studio? Only SFINAE approach seems to work.

Comment: @diko you tested all 7 approaches mentioned, and only one works in VS2015?  Well, that seems plausible.

Answer (score 9):

I assume you want your arguments to be all of the same type, probably using an integer type (I'll just use `int`). An easy approach is to leverage the parameter pack you already have:

```
template <int>
struct shape_helper { typedef int type; };

template <typename T, int... Shape>
class Array
{
public:
    T& operator()(typename shape_helper<Shape>::type...);
};
```

Comment: Somehow, I prefer not introducing additional types. Like commented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766617/variadic-templates-same-number-of-function-arguments-as-in-class?noredirect=1#comment42114016_26766617

Comment: @0x499602D2: yes, the type was intentional.

Comment: @Deduplicator: yes, using `decltype(shape, X())...` is a neat trick.