# How to make variadic template class method take function pointer as argument with type derived from function template?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Sorry the title is a mouthful. I'm working on an array class similar to the one discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766617). I want to define a "map" function that takes a user-defined function and applies it to each element of the array. For the purposes of type-checking, I'd like to define it such that the user-specified function **must** take the same number of arguments as are passed to the map function, so that

```
double f(double a, double b) { return a + b; }
Array<double,2> x, y, z; x.map(f, y, z);
```

will compile but

```
double g(double a, double b, double c) { return a + b + c; }
Array<double,2> x, y, z;. x.map(g, y, z);
```

won't, becuase `g` takes the wrong number of arguments based on what was passed to the map function.

I've tried a syntax like:

```
template<typename T, size_t ... Ns> class Array
{
    template<class ... Args> inline const Array<T, Ns...>
        map(T (*fn)(decltype(Args, double)...), Args...)
    {
        // doesn't compile
    }
}
```

I think this is close, but obviously wrong, since it doesn't compile. I'd be grateful to learn the correct syntax for an operation like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <typename T, std::size_t ... Ns>
struct Array
{
    template <typename>
    using arg_type = T;

    template <class ... Args>
    Array<T, Ns...> map(T (*fn)(arg_type<Args>...), Args...)
    {
        return {};
    }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/101885f73bbdd24c)

Comment: @Piotr_Skotnicki, thanks for your swift answer! This is exactly what I needed. I'm now stuck trying to figure out how such a function might be implemented; do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @nosuchthingasstars please raise a new question with a simplified implementation of `Array`