# Applying a function over an arbitrary number of variadic arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

This is a follow-up question to [my previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387749). I am building an Array class with basic vector math functionality. I want to define a function that lets a user map an arbitrary function over the entire array. I can already do this for predefined, binary functions (say, `operator+=` for in-place addition), but I am struggling to see how this could be done for an arbitrary number of inputs.

```
template<typename T, size_t ... Ns>
class Array
{
public:
    Array() { /* allocate memory of size product(Ns) * sizeof(T) */ }

    ~Array() { /* deallocate memory */ }

    inline Array<T, Ns...>& operator+=(const Array<T, Ns...> &rhs)                   
    {
        // simple case: predefined operation on exactly two Arrays
        T *p1 = data, *p2 = rhs.data;                                                
        while (p1 != data + size) { *p1 += *p2; p1++; p2++; }                                                                            
        return *this;                                                                
    }

    template<class ... Args>
    inline const Array<T, Ns...> map(T (*fn)(arg_type<Args>...), Args ... args)
    {
        // difficult case: arbitrary operations on a variable number of Arrays
    }

    private:
        T *data;
        size_t size;
}

// example usage
double f(double a, double b) { return a + b; }
Array<double,2> x, y, z;
x.map(f, y, z);
```

I would want something like this to loop over all elements in `y` and `z`, applying `f` to them, and storing them in `x`. I thought I could model it on my `operator+=` function, but I haven't yet found a parameter pack expansion that would let me do anything similar (and compile).

Comment: At the heart of it, you'd say something like `(data[I] = f(args[I]...))...`, which should happen in a helper function template that takes an `index_sequence<I...>` and `Args ...args`, I suppose.

Comment: is `data` always one dimensional (i.e., `Ns` always contains a single value)?

Comment: Replace data and size with a vector of T.  Write code that takes N vectors and applies a function across all of them, returning a vector of the result.  Write a constructor for your arrray class that takes a vector.  Compose those solutions, solve your problem (and stop wasting brainspace managing raw pointer lifetimes!)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, the idea was to take an arbitrary number of `Ns`, but `data` is always treated as being one-dimensional.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < Ns; ++i) data[i] = fn(args.data[i]...);` should suffice based on the description

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki replace `i < Ns` with `i < product(Ns...)`, and `data.resize(product(Ns...));`, but essentially ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this:

```
template<class T, class Array2>
using Array_Size_Copy = // expression that creates a Array<T,???>, where ??? is the Ns... of Array2 above
```

then

```
template<class F, class A0, class...Arrays>
auto array_apply( F&& f, A0&& a0, Arrays&&...arrays ) {
  using R = decay_t<decltype( f(std::declval<A0>().data.front(), std::declval<Arrays>().data.front()...) )>;

  Array_Size_Copy<R, std::decay_t<A0>> retval;

  for (int i = 0; i < a0.size(); ++i) {
    retval.data[i] = f( std::forward<A0>(a0).data[i], std::forward<Arrays>(arrays).data[i]... );
  }
  return retval;
}
```

Add some asserts (static asserts ideally) that everything is the same size.

The above function needs to be a friend possibly.  Which means you may have to set the return value instead of using `auto`, but that is just moving the type gymnastics into the declaration.